# For serial port programming in C#, When I am in the middle of a DataRecived handler, how can I jump into another DataRecieved Handler

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a serial port and a bunch of DataRecieved handler, I want one to be activated at some point if a certain condition is true in another handler.
For example

```
 // write some message to StartCommHandler

 private void StartCommHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;            
        byte[] startComResp = new byte[7];             

        if (sp.BytesToRead < 7)
            return;
        else
            sp.DataReceived -= StartCommHandler;


        sp.Read(startComResp, 0, startComResp.Length);


        if ( //true response)
        {
            // enable StartMeasureHandler and write to it:
            sp.DataReceived += StartMeasureHandler;
            // write some message to StartCommHandler
        }
        else
        {
            // enable StartCommHandler and write to it again:
            sp.DataReceived += StartCommHandler;
            // write the message to StartCommHandler
        }

      // some other code that should not be read if else is selected
    }

  private void StartMeasureHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
     //some code
    }
```

when I enable the "StartMeasureHandler" and write to it, I expect that I should jump to it and the rest of the code should be ignored. But it continues reading the rest of the code in the "StartCommHandler" .

In other words, how should I jump out of one handler to another handler

p.s.: I know that I can put codes in if else statement, but I still need to know a solution to my issue to solve a more complicated problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: There's only one good way to deal with serial stream -- with a state machine.  Make the compiler write that state machine for you and be happy.

---

Even better than swapping event handler is to not use the `DataReceived` event at all.  Use `sp.BaseStream.ReadAsync`.  Then you can write all your data handling code in blocking style which is easy, and the compiler will convert it to continuation-passing style, which performs well.

No threading to mess with.  And it bypasses the most buggy parts of the `SerialPort` class.

I've written [a blog post on the subject, which you can read for more details on why to avoid `DataReceived` and `BytesToRead`](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport).

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like a better approach for talking to a serial port. Do you know of any documents/example that uses `ReadAsync` ? Your weblog was very helpful to understand the subject, but the sample code was mainly for `EndRead` and `BeginRead`.

Comment: @Marya: [This looks like an ok example, starting at line 129](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/CqlSharp/0.12.0.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/CqlSharp/CqlSharp/Protocol/Frame.cs)  Note that reading async from serial ports, files, network sockets, pipes, etc all looks pretty much the same.  Also note that `async` functions can call each other in infinite recursive ways without blowing out the stack, because it is automatically converted to continuation-passing -- in the implementation each function does a little work and then returns, so the stack never grows.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to call

```
if ( /*true response*/)
{
    sp.DataReceived += StartMeasureHandler;
    StartMeasureHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e);
    return;
}
// ...
```

It is still just a function.

Comment: Do you mean StartCommHandler(this, e); return; ??
I tried this but it still does not jump to the other handler! It starts over the current handler.